# "File can not be opened" compiler error in MPLABX /MPLAB IDE

Tags: microcontroller, c

I'm a newbie  trying to lean PIC, I downloaded MPLAB and MPLAB X IDE. I have done this around 100 times and looked over web enough before asking this question, but my code does not compile and it always fails.

Here is what I did:

1. Created a new project using the project wizard,
2. Edited the code,
3. Copied the `16F871.H` library header in both folder (I created the project in) and added it to the header files in MPLAB IDE.

Here's my code:

```
// IFIN.C Tests an input
#include " 16F877A.h "
void main()
{
    int x; // Declare variable
    output_D(0); // Clear all outputs
    while(1) //
    {
        x = input(PIN_C0); // Get input state
        if(x = = 1)
            output_high(PIN_D0); // Change output
    }
}
```

But on compiling the code, I'm getting the following error:

```
Executing:
"C:\Program Files\PICC\Ccsc.exe" +FM "NEW.c" #__DEBUG=1 +ICD +DF +LN
+T +A +M +Z +Y=9 +EA  #__16F877A=TRUE

*** Error 18 "NEW.c" Line 2(10,23): File can not be opened
    Not in project "C:\Users\jatin\Desktop\DHAKKAN PIC\ 16F877A.h "
    Not in "C:\Program Files\PICC\devices\ 16F877A.h "
    Not in "C:\Program Files\PICC\drivers\ 16F877A.h "
*** Error 128 "NEW.c" Line 2(10,17): A #DEVICE required before this line
*** Error 12 "NEW.c" Line 6(9,10): Undefined identifier  -- output_D
*** Error 12 "NEW.c" Line 9(10,11): Undefined identifier  -- input
*** Error 51 "NEW.c" Line 10(8,9): A numeric expression must appear here

      5 Errors,  0 Warnings. Build Failed. Halting build on first failure as requested. 
BUILD FAILED: Mon Jul 08 15:09:17 2013
```

I would be grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error with respect to the header file not being found is that you have extra space in the header name. In other words, this:

```
#include " 16F877A.h "
```

should be:

```
#include "16F877A.h"
```

The other errors are probably a result of this and would go away once the header is properly included.

Note that the compiler literally takes the string inside `""` or `<>` as file name for the header file and doesn't trim whitespaces for you.